# Keep the Y axis fixed when the chart scrolls horizontally, regardless of DPI settings?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I have found a few solutions, here on SO, to keep the Y axis fixed on a horizontally scrolling chart. Unfortunately a lot of them do not work with Chart.js 2.x.x onward, or I have found them to break when the device viewing the chart has a DPI setting > 96 DPI, which is a deal breaker for me as I will have such devices visiting my website that uses Chart.js.

My best solution at the moment is to use the animation - onComplete and onProgress options - https://jsfiddle.net/EmmaLouise/vcbg0jdn/1/.

```
maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                titleFontSize: 0,
                titleMarginBottom: 0,
                bodyFontSize: 12
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: function () {
                    if (!rectangleSet) {
                        var sourceCanvas = chartTest.chart.canvas;
                        var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width;
                        var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;
                        var targetCtx = document.getElementById("axis-Test").getContext("2d");
                        targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth;
                        targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);

                        var sourceCtx = sourceCanvas.getContext('2d');
                        sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
                        rectangleSet = true;
                    }
                },
                onProgress: function () {
                    if (rectangleSet === true) {
                        var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width;
                        var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                        var sourceCtx = chartTest.chart.canvas.getContext('2d');
                        sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, I am still trying to work out how to scale this with DPI settings, if I can at all.

I find it hard to believe that the only way to have a fixed axis involves having an animation workaround but that has been all I could find in my research online over the last couple of days.

Has anybody else managed to achieve this in a simpler way, or resolved the DPI issue? Admittedly I am very new to using Chart.js, so I may be approaching this wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution in the end. The problem was that the Chart itself was being scaled correctly to match the DPR of the device, but the axis being animated was not.

Scaling the axis myself resolved the problem - https://jsfiddle.net/EmmaLouise/eb1aqpx8/3/:

```
var scale = window.devicePixelRatio;                       

                        var sourceCanvas = chartTest.chart.canvas;
                        var copyWidth = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].width - 10;
                        var copyHeight = chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartTest.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;

                        var targetCtx = document.getElementById("axis-Test").getContext("2d");

                        targetCtx.scale(scale, scale);
                        targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth * scale;
                        targetCtx.canvas.height = copyHeight * scale;

                        targetCtx.canvas.style.width = `${copyWidth}px`;
                        targetCtx.canvas.style.height = `${copyHeight}px`;
                        targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale, 0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);

                        var sourceCtx = sourceCanvas.getContext('2d');

                        // Normalize coordinate system to use css pixels.

                        sourceCtx.clearRect(0, 0, copyWidth * scale, copyHeight * scale);
                        rectangleSet = true;
```